# write a copy of an int to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, scope, scipy

I'm using "SciPy.optimize" and have some trouble with generating some constrains.

I'm trying to add an entry to a dictionary using a loop. The index i of the loop should be written to the dictionary. But there is only a reference written to the dictionary. All the functions are {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: MyFunction(x,True, 19)}  Because 19 is the max value of i. (The array has 20 objects..) So the result is, the ouput of all functions is 19.

```
con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': MyFirstFunction} 
cons = ([con1])

for i, m in enumerate(myobject.getAsNpArray()):
    cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: MyFunction(x,True, i)})


def MyFunction(x,myBool, i):
    print(i)
    #do some fancy stuff
```

How can I fix the problem? Something like this does not work:

```
cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: MyFunction(x,True, copy.copy(i))})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `lambda`'s body reads `i` from the surrounding scope when the `lambda` is *called*, not when it's *defined*. Since the `lambda` is called after the loop completes, when it goes back to read `i` from the nested scope, it gets the *final* value of `i`.

A simple solution is to bind `i` as a defaulted argument of the `lambda`; argument defaults are bound at function definition time, not call time, so you can use that to lock in `i` when you make the `lambda`:

```
cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, i=i: MyFunction(x, True, i)})
#                            change is here ^^^^^
```